# Nabla operator ∇, applications?

Tags: operators, differentiation, big-list

I'm a math student I'm making one project of problems involving the **operator ∇ or "Nabla operator**. Just to make a hint of: gradient, divergence and curl.

I need more examples of it's uses and its applications especially on physics?

**Anyone has any idea of where I can find some useful material on this field? I couldn't find anything scientific in my country**

Comment: In what way do you think of $\nabla$ as a Hamiltonian operator?

Comment: We have a course of vectorial analysis or vectorial calculus.   If we write ∇φ as [i(∂/∂x)+j(∂/∂y)+k(∂/∂z)]φ, we can then call the bracket ∇.
By itself ∇ has no meaning (just as d/dx alone has no meaning; we must put some
function after it to be differentiated). However, it is useful to use ∇ much as we
use d/dx to indicate a certain operation.  Now I have to make some research of connections between this operator and physics, but I need some more scientific material (literature) with more examples, (electromagnetism or gravitational field..)

Comment: I'm afraid that your question will confuse everyone. Yes, $\nabla$ sometimes in the past at least in some countries was called as the Hamilton operator. The problem is I really doubt you find much people that call it this way now because the words "Hamilton operator" and "Hamiltonian" are reserved for completely different object.

Comment: Maybe you're right, it's better to use it as simply "nablla operator", but yes, in our literature its also called "Hamilton operator"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $\nabla$ operator, besides curl, divergence and gradient (who have major applications in fluid dynamics and electromagnetism), has another application which is the laplacian, which can be defined as *the divergence of a gradient*, i.e, for some scalar function $f$, we would have $\nabla^2 f$ as its laplacian. The laplacian plays important roles in electromagnetism, heat conductivity, waves, and so on.

As for the hamiltonian operador, denoted by $\hat{H}$, it has mainly applications in both classical and quantum mechanics, and it describes the total energy of a system. The hamiltonian operator also appears in the Schrödinger equation.

As a resource for finding its applications in physics, i would recommend Arfken's "Mathematical Methods for Physicists". It is mainly a mathematics book, but it shows many applications of math in physics.